# Does adding eventListener with same params null/replace previous eventListeners?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I've inherited a large, legacy Flex project and the deeper I get into the code, the more concerned I am becoming. For example, I am looking at code for a "window" type image viewer within the app. Every time it is displayed, the eventListeners below are added and never removed.

Since these are strong references and never removed, that is one problem but this repeatedly adding eventListeners is giving me pause. The "window" can be displayed and hidden many times in the lifecycle of the app.

**My question:** does this mean that is has **n** = (4 * number of times displayed) eventListeners? *(...shudder).*

This is a huge project revision on a tight budget so I am trying to determine if I fix this sort of thing or just let it go.

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are **different** eventlisteners, they will be added multiple times. If they all refer to the same function, it will be overridden each time, calling the specific function only once.

try out the following short example to see what i mean:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite(); //some sort of displayobject with EventDispatcher capabilities
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("hey");
}
```

pressing on the Sprite will give you a console output of "hey", not two "hey"s.
Now consider the following:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick2);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
trace("hey");
}

function onClick2(e:MouseEvent):void{
trace("sup");
}
```

This will give you an output of "hey" and "sup" once you press on the Sprite.

If you are really concerned, you could just give the event listener a weak reference. I don't know how complex the project is you're working on, but implementing something to get rid of all eventlisteners at once (like, waiting for Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE and then manually removing the listeners) shouldn't be too time-intensive.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I meant the same eventListeners being added -so at least there are not possibly zillions of orphaned eventListeners. I can go through and do weak refs but there are **lots** of classes, etc. Do you know if calling removeEventListener for a non-existent eventListener throws an error?

Comment: it should not, but you can put an if conditional with `hasEventListener(type:String)` in front of it if you want to be sure.

Comment: In my experience, equal listeners also stack under some circumstances, the most pronounced event to stack listeners is `Event.ENTER_FRAME`.

Comment: @TOMATO No, if there's no event listener by the referred parameters, the `removeEventListener` will just skip.

Comment: @TOMATO Be careful with changing to weak listeners.  I've been burned by switching to a weak listener, only to realize that the listener was the only remaining reference to that class!